# Nginx API Gateway in Docker Compose

Tags: docker, rest, nginx, docker-compose, reverse-proxy

*(Disclaimer: I've seen a lot of version of this question asked on here but none seem to really answer my question.)*

I want to use NGINX as an API Gateway to route requests to microservice APIs in docker-compose.

For my sample app, I have two microservice APIs (A and B). Any request endpoint that starts with `/a` should go to API-A and any request endpoint that starts with `/b` should go to API-B.

Some issues I've had are:

- I want paths like `/a/foo/bar` to match API-A but not `/ab/foo`
- I want routing to work regardless of whether or not the path ends in a `/` (*aka* both `/a/foo` and `/a/foo/` work)

My `docker-compose` file looks like this:

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  gateway:
    build:
      context: ./api-gw
    ports:
      - 8000:80
  apia:
    build:
      context: ./api-a
    ports:
      - 8000
  apib:
    build:
      context: ./api-b
    ports:
      - 8000
```

and my sample NGINX config file looks like this:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location ^~ /a {
       proxy_pass   http://apia:8000/;
    }

    location ^~ /b {
       proxy_pass   http://apib:8000/;
    }

}
```

How can I setup my NGINX config to properly route my requests?

*Thanks for your help!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change your Nginx regex rules to these :

match for Api-A :

```
^a(\/.*)?
```

match for Api-B :

```
^b(\/.*)?
```